# How can I specify library versions in setup.py?

Tags: python, buildout

In my `setup.py` file, I've specified a few libraries needed to run my project:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires = [
        'django-pipeline',
        'south'
    ]
)
```

How can I specify required versions of these libraries?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I'm not sure about buildout, however, for setuptools/distribute, you specify version info with the comparison operators (like `==`, `>=`, or `<=`).

For example:

```
install_requires = ['django-pipeline==1.1.22', 'south>=0.7']
```

See the [Python packaging documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)

Comment: to undestand the setup.py better [read the docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: I know setup.py with distutils/setuptools/distribute, does buildout use this as well?  I've never used it before, and wasn't sure why the OP mentioned buildout.

Comment: Buildout honors the `install_requires` entry of packages, including version requirements. It uses setuptools under the hood for this.

Comment: Nice, thanks, that answers my question. I forgot that Buildout used setuptools under the hood.

Comment: How can I specify the version of python?

Comment: Does setup.py also honour the versions I have installed in my current env? Or does it just fetch the latest ones available?

Comment: @qed `python_requires='>=3',` 
[More information](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires)

Comment: @TarsisAzevedo unfortunately the docs does not give these examples, as of April 2021. That page doesn’t even mention “ install_requires”

Comment: what if I want to accept any patch (x.x.any) version?

Comment: I don't know how much of this might be new from the last comments, but there is documentation [on pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/) about dependency resolution, version operators (says to see [PEP-0440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/) for details in includes ranges like `==3.1.*`) python.org also [describes install_requires](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) on a different page.

Answer (score 6):

You can add them to your `requirements.txt` file along with the version.

For example:

```
django-pipeline==1.1.22
south>=0.7
```

and then in your `setup.py`

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(...
install_requires=required,
...)
```

**Reading from the docs -**

> It is not considered best practice to use `install_requires` to pin
> dependencies to specific versions, or to specify sub-dependencies
> (i.e. dependencies of your dependencies). This is overly-restrictive,
> and prevents the user from gaining the benefit of dependency
> upgrades.

https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/#id5